# How to delete all of the topics in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ with the C# client library.  I created 10,000 topics with random names as part of a test for evaluation purposes and now I can't get rid of the topics.  ActiveMQ grinds to a halt with this number of topics so I need them out of the system.  Here is what I have tried so far, and none of it has worked.  I'm running ActiveMQ as a Windows service.

- Delete all of the files and folders in ACTIVEMQ_HOME\Data
- Turn off all persistence
- Delete all of the files and folders in the persistence folder
- Delete the entire ACTIVEMQ_HOME directory and reinstall it in a different folder

I've traced the file activity and cannot find any file that is written to when a topic is created or deleted.

I realize that the .NET client library is a little light on functionality, so I can't even get a list of all the topics programmatically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to your broker configuration file, open the file for editing on the broker element, add the following attribute:

```
deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true"
```

This will cause all previous topics & queues, and their pending messages to be deleted from your kaha store when you restart your broker.

Have Fun!

Comment: @NSA where will I find configuration file.

Comment: @NSA I found it.and tried it's working great. If you know is there any tutorial for this type of tips. suggest me.

Comment: How should I do this in version >5.10

Answer (score 2):

This question might be old, but a quick and easy way to totally purge all data in ActiveMQ alongwith all queues and topics is to go to the following path:

```
<ActiveMQ_Installation_Directory>/data
```

And delete all files in that.

Now once you restart AMQ it will start as a fresh, clean install.